# C multi-thread wordcount program segmentation fault issue

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I've been racking my brain against this program for a couple months now.  This was an assignment of a class I took last semester and while I passed, I could never make this one assignment work correctly (Seg Fault).  I welcome any help or tips but I greatly appreciate explanations with answers to follow along.

This program is supposed to receive a filename that contains a list of filenames (240 for my example).  Those files are located in a folder within the same directory as the list and the program.  This program is supposed to take this list and parse it for 4 threads, splitting the filenames evenly for each thread (60 per thread for my example).  Each thread then takes this list of 60 file names and opens each file one by one performing a *WordCount* function on each file.  Once the threads complete their tasks, they are supposed to print the results for each file in order with each thread in its own block(i.e. Thread1 Results | Thread2 Results | Thread 3 Results, etc...).

I've debugged quite a bit and know that up until the threads are created everything works as it is supposed to.  My problem seems to be during thread launch/execution.  I've tried adding mutex to the mix but sadly it hasn't helped.  I seem to be missing something or over thinking something as some of my class mates have shown me their much more compact code.  Please assist.  Thanks!

Here is the Main:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MaxLine 200
#define NUMTHREADS 4

char Line[MaxLine];
pthread_mutex_t Lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct thread {
    int id;
    char file;
}ThreadData;

/* ThreadFunction will give each thread its processes to execute */
 void *threadFunc (void *td) {
    ThreadData *data = (ThreadData*)td;
    int thread_num=data->id;
    char filename=data->file;
    printf("thread debug tid: %d and file: %c",thread_num, filename);
    pthread_mutex_trylock(&Lock);
    FILE *fn = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fn == NULL) {
        error("ERROR: Opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(Line, sizeof(Line), fn) != NULL) {
        CountWord(thread_num, Line);
    }
    fclose(fn);
    free(data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Lock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buf[20];
    int c, i, t, tnum, QUEUETOTAL;
    pthread_t thread[NUMTHREADS];
    ThreadData td[NUMTHREADS];

    if (argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Usage must be Countfile filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    char const* const filename = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if ( file == 0 ){
        printf( "Could not open file!\n" );
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Count iterations of while loop to divide files among threads. */
    while (fgets(Line, sizeof(Line), file)){
        QUEUETOTAL++;
    }

    /* Divide work for threads. */
    int thread2taskstart=(QUEUETOTAL/NUMTHREADS); //60
    int thread3taskstart=(QUEUETOTAL/NUMTHREADS)*2; //120
    int thread4taskstart=(QUEUETOTAL/NUMTHREADS)*3; //180
    // QUEUETOTAL = 240

    rewind(file);
    FILE *tempfile1  = fopen("temp1.txt","w");
    for (i=0; i<thread2taskstart; i++) {
        // populate tempfile1 with entries 1-60
        if(fgets(Line,sizeof(Line),file)!=NULL) {
            fputs(Line,tempfile1);
            //printf("Debug temp1: %s",Line);
        }
    }
    fclose(tempfile1);
    FILE *tempfile2  = fopen("temp2.txt","w");
    for (i=thread2taskstart; i<thread3taskstart; i++) {
        // populate tempfile2 with entries 60-120
        if(fgets(Line,sizeof(Line),file)!=NULL) {
            fputs(Line,tempfile2);
            //printf("Debug temp2: %s",Line);
        }
    }
    fclose(tempfile2);
    FILE *tempfile3  = fopen("temp3.txt","w");
    for (i=thread3taskstart; i<thread4taskstart; i++) {
        // populate tempfile3 with entries 120-180
        if(fgets(Line,sizeof(Line),file)!=NULL) {
            fputs(Line,tempfile3);
            //printf("Debug temp3: %s",Line);
        }
    }
    fclose(tempfile3);
    FILE *tempfile4  = fopen("temp4.txt","w");
    for (i=thread4taskstart; i<=QUEUETOTAL; i++) {
        // populate tempfile3 with entries 180-240
        if(fgets(Line,sizeof(Line),file)!=NULL) {
            fputs(Line,tempfile4);
            //printf("Debug temp4: %s",Line);
        }
    }
    fclose(tempfile4);
    fclose(file);

    /* Prepare parameters & launch (4) threads.  Wait for threads
    to finish & print out results as specified in assignment. */
    printf("Counting files …\n");

    for(t=0;t<NUMTHREADS;t++){
        tnum=t+1;
        snprintf(buf, "temp%d.txt", tnum);
        printf("debug tnum and array: %d and %s\n",tnum, buf);
        td[t].id = tnum;
        td[t].file = buf;
        // Creates a new thread for each temp file.
        pthread_create(&thread[t], NULL, threadFunc, td);
    }
    // Joins threads.
    printf("debug: printing threads \n");
    for(t=0;t<NUMTHREADS;t++){
    pthread_join(thread[t], NULL);
    printf("-------------------------  Processes finished for Thread %d  ----------------------- \n",t+1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Count Function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int CountWord(int tinfo, char cfile){
    int i;
    int ccount = 0;
    int wcount = 0;
    int lcount = 0;
    FILE *fname;
    char fn[strlen(cfile) + 18];
    sprintf(fn, "./CountingFolder/%s", cfile);
    printf("Debug: %s\n", fn);
    fname = fopen(fn, "r");
    if (fname == NULL) {
        error("ERROR: Opening file");
    }
    while ((i = fgetc(fname)) != EOF){
        if (i == '\n') {
            lcount++;
        }
        if (i == '\t' || i == ' '){
            wcount++;
        }
        ccount++;
    }
    printf("Threadid %d processes %s which has %d characters, %d words and %d lines\n", tinfo, cfile, ccount, wcount, lcount);
    fclose(fname);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using `pthread_mutex_trylock` without checking the result. What happens when it failed to acquire the lock?

Comment: in function: CountWord(): when a file fails to open, do NOT try to read from the file

Comment: in function: CountWord():  in the 'while' loop: consider the condition where a line in the input file contains some combination of tabs and spaces with no other characters, including/ especially at the beginning of the line.  And proper text has 2 spaces after the end of each sentence.   Suggest: 1) search stackoverflow for examples (probably without the multiple threads) of extracting words from a file.   The good examples will have a two state machine implemented in-word and not-in-word .  start in the not-in-word state.

Comment: if any of the input files do not have a newline as the last character, then the line count and word count will be incorrect

Comment: if the executable and the input files are all in the same directory, then why the use of a path to the input files?

Comment: in function: main, regarding this line: 'fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Usage must be Countfile filename\n", argv[0]);'  The format string is missing a '%s" for the argv[0] parameter

Comment: in main, when the number of parameters is not correct, this line: 'exit(0);' is executed.  0 means 'success'  strongly suggest using: 'exit( EXIT_FAILURE );'

Comment: regarding this line: 'FILE *tempfile1  = fopen("temp1.txt","w");' Always check (!=NULL) the returned value (tempfile1) to assure the operation was successful.   If not successful, do NOT try writing to the file.  This goes for all the output files in main

Comment: the 'rewind()' function is really more for tape drives.  Suggest using 'int result = fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET );'  Then check the value in result to determine if the fseek() was successful

Comment: the td[]->file is a single character, so it will never contain the full file name and one char is not big enough to contain a pointer.  Regarding this kind of line in main(): 'td[t].file = buf;'   'td[t].file' is a single character, it needs to be an array of char and set via strcpy( td[t].file, buf );   It cannot be a 'char *' because 'buf' is overlayed with each new output file

Comment: this line: 'char filename=data->file;' copies one character.  then that one character is being used as the complete file name

Comment: You could greatly simplify the code by not producing the intermediate files.  Just have a unique 'FILE *' for each thread, pass the original file name and the start and length values to the thread the thread can fopen the file, then read lines until getting to the desired start point, then loop, handling each file name and its' contents. until the desired stop point.  No mutex needed, no intermediate files needed, greatly shrink the code.  Do not use common I/O buffers I.E. 'Line[]' instead use local/on the stack buffers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Probably a typo. But

`int CountWord(int tinfo, char cfile){ .. }`

should be

```
int CountWord(int tinfo, char *cfile){ .. }
```

2) You are passing the same `buf` to all threads from `main()`. Data race and undefined behaviour.

3) None of the `snprintf()` calls take the `size` argument. Undefined behaviour.

4) Since all threads work on different data, you don't need a lock at all.

5) You didn't allocate `td` array. So you can't call `free(data);` in the thread function. Undefined behaviour.

There may be more issues with the code but the segfault is likely because of (3) or (5).

Comment: Right. There's no need to use a lock because a variable that reads lines is global. But it should really be a local variable.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Globals don't need locking? Why's that then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant (in my prev comment) that a variable that's solely used to read lines and should be local and that's not a reason a introduce a lock in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code here

```
snprintf(buf, "temp%d.txt", tnum);
printf("debug tnum and array: %d and %s\n",tnum, buf);
td[t].id = tnum;
td[t].file = buf;
```

the last line assigns a pointer into the `file` field of this struct

```
typedef struct thread {
    int id;
    char file;
}ThreadData;
```

Shouldn't it be `char *file;` ? I don't have `thread.h` in MSVC so I can't compile it. Surely you have all warnings enabled??

Comment: It should fail to compile if this is the case. Definitely something odd going on here (possibly lack of deep copy) but it could also be an issue with the question.